# Where's the error in the code? Node.js error code ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END

Tags: node.js-connect

I created a file http1.js. In browser, when I type `localhost:5000/about` I get localhost refused to connect and in code I got the error:

```
const http = require('http')
const server = http.create Server((req, res) => {

    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.end('Welcome to our home page')
    }
    if (req.url === '/about') {

        res.end('Here is our short history')

    }

    res.end(

        `<h1>Oops!</h1>
     
         <p>We can't seem to find the page your are looking for</p>
     
         <a  h ref ="/">Back home page</a>`

    )

}
)
server.listen(5000)
```

The exception thrown is this one when I type `localhost:5000/about`  and  refresh the  page this is the error which I am encountering in my code. How to solve it, and also but there is no issue when I type `localhost:5000` I got correct result.

```
  node:events:490
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
  
  Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
      at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:1009:15)
      at Server.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Suresh\pratice_Tuotorial(JN)\.vscode\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:9:9)
      at Server.emit (node:events:512:28)
      at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1086:12)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
  Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
      at emitErrorNt (node:_http_outgoing:849:9)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
  }
```

Comment: Clarify the question, please @Vaisnavi. And please, make more clear code and text for improving the community.

Comment: The problem is  , In browser when I did localhost:5000 there was no issue. But when I did localhost:5000/about  in the browser  its showing  localhost refused to connect.

Comment: ok, look at the answer @Vaishnavi. I've explained you what happens.

Comment: yeah , just now I saw thanks for clearing it

Comment: if it it solved the question, please mark as correct response. Thanks @Vaishnavi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving two responses when accessing `localhost:5000/about` and `localhost:5000/`. After telling the http-client (e.g.browser) that it won't receive more from the server with the `response.end()`.

Here's how you have to do, for giving just one response always:

```
const http = require('http')
const server = http.create Server((req, res) => {

    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.end('Welcome to our home page')
    } else if (req.url === '/about') {
        res.end('Here is our short history')
    } else {
        res.end(

            `<h1>Oops!</h1>
     
         <p>We can't seem to find the page your are looking for</p>
     
         <a  h ref ="/">Back home page</a>`
        )
    }
}
)
```

Now, this code just returns one response.

If you want to understand why your code didn't return an `Exception` when typing `localhost:5000`, it was because your code did not execute the contents in any `if` and just returned one response.

1. `localhost:5000`: one response -> OK
2. `localhost:5000/`: two responses -> Exception
3. `localhost:5000/about`: two responses -> Exception

If you need to send more than one response, the way is using `response.write()` instead of `response.end()`. [Here](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/node-js/express-js/response-send-end-write-difference/)'s more information .